# System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine output location for C# DLL

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

I have a custom C# DLL that is being used in Unity. 
I want to be able to see the output of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`that is called from the C# DLL when I run the Unity Editor. What is the location where these Debug messages get stored too?

For example, if you use `UnityEngine.Debug.WriteLine()` in Unity, it will be saved to the debugging output text file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know What unity3d can do for you, but these recommendation may help you to solve your problem.

1. use Trace.WriteLine instead of Debug.WriteLine if you are not sure
   your c# dll in debug mode.(TRACE or DEBUG preprocessor should be defined)
2. you should specify your Tracelistener or DebugListener in config file or in code like follows:

   ```
     <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4" >
       <listeners>

         <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData="myTraceLog.txt" />
       </listeners>
     </trace>
   </system.diagnostics>
   ```

   equivalent c# code:

   ```
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("myListenerLog.txt", "myListener"));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Debug.WriteLine will send output to the Windows debug output pipe. You can visualize that stream with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview